# Automounting internal partition and usb

Tags: arch-linux, udev, fstab, automounting

I'm running arch Linux with i3 window manager and I'm wondering if there's a way to replicate Ubuntu behavior about auto mounting internal partitions and USB. More precisely:

- Mount all partitions and USB to `/media/$USER/$DEV_LABEL` or `/media/$USER/$DEV_UUID` at boot
- Unmount all previously mounted partitions before shutdown or reboot
- For all USB, unmount them when they are ejected and mount them when inserted

I know that for the internal partitions i have to add entry to `/etc/fstab` (I tried and I succeeded), but i want something more dynamic.
I tried read something about udev rules, but there's nothing that explains how to accomplish those tasks.
Thanks, Federico.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gvfs` and `udisks` to automatically mount USB devices. You can do the same using a file manager that supports automatic mounting. I use `PCManFM` and `gvfs` and my USB devices are automatically mounted to `/run/media/$USER/$DEV_LABEL`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try. In the meantime I've implemented some udev rules with a couple of bash scripts. When I'm done writing them I'll post an answer with all I've come up.